# Control servo with 4 wires with Blynk

Tags: arduino, motor, servo, esp8266

im a beginner in coding and I was wondering if I could control an old servo using the Blynk app. I want to control the direction, so it can unroll the screen up and down. We opened the servo to look inside and there was some kind of sensor hooked up to the green and yellow wire. Red and black are power supply. Does somebody know how can I control the motor using an ESP8266 or an Arduino? It runs on 12-16V, 0.7A.

Thank you very much!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: have you actually done any research about how to control a motor with an Arduino?

Comment: yes I have. But every motor I saw had 3 wires. And as I said, im a noob at programming, so I would be very happy if you could help me

Comment: that is odd, i googled `how to drive a motor with arduino` and i did not see any with 3 wires .... here is one of the hits https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kv-9mxVaVzE